# Multiple sql inserts in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a code as following :

```
Offre o = offreRepository.save(offre);
for(OffreCompetence offreCompetence : offre.getOffreCompetences()) {
    offreCompetence.setOffre(o);
    offreCompetenceRepository.save(offreCompetence);
}
```

So as you can see I'm calling the `offreRepository` for the first time to insert an `Offre` into database, then I call `offreCompetenceRepository` multiple times to insert each `OffreCompetence`in the `Offre` to the database.

The problem here is that I'm making a connection to the database multiple times.

Isn't there any other method to do these inserts in once ?

## Edit :

I tried to add this line :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="offre")
   private Set<OffreCompetences> offreCompetences;
```

But the `offreCompetences` are not added to the database, when I checked the log file I noticed that Hibernate doesn't INSERT them but I can't find them in the database, I think the problem is when he try to add `offreCompetences` he doesn't know the id of the `Offre` for them :

```
Hibernate: insert into offre (date_expiration, date_publication, duree_mission, email_sended, etat, niveau_experience, nombre_postulant, nombre_vue, poste, profil_recherche, titre, code_type_contrat, code_ville) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2016-07-28 16:08:13.237 DEBUG 10736 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into offre_competence (competence, niveau_requis, offre) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into offre_competence (competence, niveau_requis, offre) values (?, ?, ?)
2016-07-28 16:08:13.304 DEBUG 10736 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into offre_competence (competence, niveau_requis, offre) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into offre_competence (competence, niveau_requis, offre) values (?, ?, ?)
2016-07-28 16:08:13.339 DEBUG 10736 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into offre_competence (competence, niveau_requis, offre) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into offre_competence (competence, niveau_requis, offre) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the parent object is set in every object in the list. The Cascade persist will ensure that the object and its children are saved and linked correctly. Unfortunately, if it is not explicitly set it will not create the relationship in the database.

```
    for(OffreCompetence offreCompetence : offre.getOffreCompetences()) {
        offreCompetence.setOffre(offre);
    }
    Offre o = offreRepository.save(offre);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `CascadeType` on the offre.offreCompetences relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Offre {

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="offre")
   private Set<OffreCompetences> offreCompetences 
   ...
}

@Entity
public class OffreCompetences {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "..." )
    private Offre offre;
}
```

Once you do this, offreCompetences will be saved when you save offre.

Look at the [JPA docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) for `CascadeType`.

Comment: I realize we have a bit of a language barrier, but what does 'I can't find them in the database' mean? Did you commit the transaction? How are you looking for them? Basically, you really need to provide some details about **how** you are doing things for us to provide help. Regarding 'he doesn't know the id of the Offre', hibernate should handle this mapping for you. The '?' in the log are just placeholders.

Comment: thanks for your time, I've resolved my problem thanks to @KubenT answer's

Comment: Just to point out, your original example had you setting the offre in the offreCompetency. You must have removed it in between. The `CascadeType` is what solved your problem.